# IE troubles - complex phone number error checking in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm writing a piece of code to validate three phone numbers.  The logic is, one of the numbers must be valid, otherwise there's an error on line 3 of the code.  It works perfectly well except for in IE. IE doesn't detect the error. Are there any pieces in this code that don't work properly in IE?

```
  //check first homephone
//check second workphone
//check third cellphone
// if nothing = 10 then something is wrong
var numLengthHome = ($('.homephone > .validPhone:eq(0)').val().length) + ($('.homephone > .validPhone:eq(1)').val().length) + ($('.homephone > .validPhone:eq(2)').val().length);
var numLengthWork = ($('.workphone  > .validPhone:eq(0)').val().length) + ($('.workphone  > .validPhone:eq(1)').val().length) + ($('.workphone  > .validPhone:eq(2)').val().length); var numLengthCell = ($('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(0)').val().length) + ($('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(1)').val().length) + ($('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(2)').val().length);

var num1 = true; var num2 = true; var num3 = true; // all assume the numbers are fine until proven otherwise

 if ((($('.homephone > .validPhone:eq(0)').val()) && ($('.homephone > .validPhone:eq(1)').val()) && ($('.homephone > .validPhone:eq(2)').val()) && (numLengthHome == 10))) {
 $('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(2)').parents('.formgroup').addClass('error');
 num1 = false;      
} 
else if ((($('.workphone > .validPhone:eq(0)').val()) && ($('.workphone > .validPhone:eq(1)').val()) && ($('.workphone > .validPhone:eq(2)').val()) && (numLengthWork == 10))) {
 $('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(2)').parents('.formgroup').addClass('error'); 
num2 = false; 
  } else if ((($('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(0)').val()) && ($('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(1)').val()) && ($('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(2)').val()) && (numLengCell == 10))) {
 $('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(2)').parents('.formgroup').addClass('error'); num3 = false;
} else {
 $('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(2)').parents('.formgroup').removeClass('error');
        }

 if((num1 == true) || (num2 == true) || (num3 == true)) {       
 $('.cellphone > .validPhone:eq(2)').parents('.formgroup').removeClass('error');

 }
```

HTML:

```
 <tr>
<td class="label_col indent">
      <div class="label">
        Home Phone:
       </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="ucRelatedContentControls_ctl01_divHomePhone" class="formgroup homephone">
            <input name="ucRelatedContentControls$ctl01$txtHomePhone1" maxlength="3" id="ucRelatedContentControls_ctl01_txtHomePhone1" class="input_10 input_stacked validPhone" type="text"><span class="pipe">-</span>
            <input name="ucRelatedContentControls$ctl01$txtHomePhone2" maxlength="3" id="ucRelatedContentControls_ctl01_txtHomePhone2" class="input_10 input_stacked validPhone" type="text"><span class="pipe">-</span>
            <input name="ucRelatedContentControls$ctl01$txtHomePhone3" maxlength="4" id="ucRelatedContentControls_ctl01_txtHomePhone3" class="input_10 input_stacked validPhone" type="text">


            <div class="tooltip">
                <div class="tooltip_arrow">
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip_message">
                    ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ...
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="invalid">
                <div class="invalid_arrow">
                </div>
                <div class="invalid_message">
                    Error message
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

(don't mind the tables - not in the scope of the project I'm doing :)

Comment: I'm actually starting to think it has to do with the selectors - I'm testing for IE7 and above. No worries about 6.

Comment: Not sure on your bug, but when checking booleans against a true/false value you can simply use `if(num1)` instead of `if(num1 == true)`, or `if(!num1)` instead of `if(num1 == false)`

Comment: Also `$('.homephone > .validPhone:eq(0)').val()` is a getting, surely `if( $('.homephone > .validPhone:eq(0)').val() )` doesn't do anything?

Comment: When I see the same jQuery selectors used over and over again I cringe at how badly the code performs. Store things you use into variables! Use the variables.

Comment: @epascarello Hmm you're right... sorry, brand new to JS.  Thanks for the tip!